# Wrap column in own command

Tags: tables

In the manner of separating visual appearance from semantics, I've defined a new command to style words that describe parameters:

```
\newcommand{\param}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
```

Is it possible to wrap a column in a table automatically in this command? I'm looking for something like the common

```
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \( }c<{ \) } }
```

only with my own commands, which needs a pair of brackets instead of parenthesis

```
\newcolumntype{P}{ >{ \param\{ }l<{ \} }
```

Obviously brackets don't work, as they mess up the `\newcolumntype` definition.

I also would like to be able to exclude a cell from this behaviour, in order to style the table header differently. Similar how `siunitx` handles and `S`-type columns. There you can exclude a cell by wrapping them in `{brackets}`.

---

I realize that in this case I could achieve this by switching to monospace font for the whole column

```
\newcolumntype{P}{ >{\tt}l }
```

and switching to normal font for the header `\normalfont{header}`. But this fixes the visual representation to monospace font. I might later decide to change the appearance of the `\param` macro to something like `\newcommand{\param}[1]{Parameter \texttt{#1}}` and the column type would not automatically adapt. This defeats the purpose of using the special column type in the first place.

---

Example table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{P}{ >{\tt}l }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{PsS[table-figures-integer=4,table-figures-decimal=1]}
    \toprule
    {Parameter}  & {Unit} & {Value} \\
    \midrule
    MIN\_RADIUS  & \mm    & 8.3     \\
    PENALTY      &  -     & 1000    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: example table]

Comment: `\newcommand{\param}{\ttfamily}`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my question correctly. I might later on decide to define `\newcommand{\param}[1]{Paramter \texttt{#1}}`. I want to adjust the column type to the command, not the other way around.

Comment: Define `\tabparam` and amend that when you change `\param`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`collcell`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/collcell/collcell.pdf). Note, however, that the `{...}` trick will not work for the `P` column like for `S` or `s`. Use `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` as a workaround.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,collcell}

\newcommand{\param}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}{ >{\collectcell\param}l<{\endcollectcell} }

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{PsS[table-format=4.1]}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Parameter}  & {Unit} & {Value} \\
\midrule
MIN\_RADIUS  & \mm   & 8.3     \\
PENALTY      & {--}  & 1000    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\renewcommand{\param}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{PsS[table-format=4.1]}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Parameter}  & {Unit} & {Value} \\
\midrule
MIN\_RADIUS  & \mm   & 8.3     \\
PENALTY      & {--}  & 1000    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The second table has been typeset with a modified `\param` macro in order to show that it only depends on the current definition of `\param`.

[image]